# Change number format in Word of data imported from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to change the format of numbers that I import from an Excel sheet and print them in the Word document table with the format "0.00%".

Prechanging the format in Excel is no use, because when the data is transcribed it pastes the original number.

```vb
Const stWordDocument As String = "Doc.docm"

Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdCell As Word.Cell
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim lnCountItems As Long
Dim vaData As Variant

Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wbBook.ActiveSheet
vaData = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, "F"), Cells(rcount, lastcol0)).Value

Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("https://orgindustrie-my.sharepoint.com/personal/Different_person_org_com/Documents/folder/subfolder/subsubfolder/Doc.docm")
wdApp.Visible = True

For i = 1 To lastcol0 - 5 Step 1
    lnCountItems = 1
    For Each wdCell In wdDoc.Tables(1).Columns(i).Cells
        If lnCountItems = rcount + 1 Then
            Exit For
        Else
            Cell_Text = wdCell.Range.Text
            whte = IsNumeric(vaData(lnCountItems, i))
            If whte = True Then
                wdCell.Range.Text = Format(Cell_Text, "0.00%")
            End If
            wdCell.Range.Text = vaData(lnCountItems, i)
            lnCountItems = lnCountItems + 1
        End If
    Next wdCell
Next i
```

This identifies all Excel data as numeric, and all Word data as non numeric, so this is always true.

```
whte = IsNumeric(vaData(lnCountItems, i))
```

This also doesn't change the format of the output in the line

```
wdCell.Range.Text = Format(Cell_Text, "0.00%")
```

If I change it to Word data it is always false.

```
whte = IsNumeric(Cell_Text)
```

It always comes in the form

Word example output
[image: Word Image]

Excel example source
[image: Excel image]

I tried

```
wdCell.Range.Text = FormatPercent(Cell_Text, 2)
```

but error "Type Mismatch" appears.

I also tried

```
wdCell.Range.Text.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
```

here, error "Invalid Qualifier" appears or "Method or data member not found" when I remove `.Text`.

These numbers come from a `.Sumifs` line.

```
.Cells(i, lastcol).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range(Cells(rcount, "E"), Cells(2, "E")), Range(Cells(rcount, "B"), Cells(2, "B")), Cells(i, "B"))
```

```vb
rcount= last row with information
lastcol0= last column with information 
lastcol= last column without information ( basically lastcol0 + 1 )
```

Comment: You can try to use the value of the cell, and not its text for the _format_ method (e.g. _wdCell.Range.Text = Format(wdCell , "0.00%")_

Comment: `wdCell.Range.Text` includes the two-character "end of cell" marker, so you need to trim that off  `Cell_Text = Left(Cell_Text, Len(Cell_Text)-2)` before checking for numeric/non-numeric...

Comment: Also you do this `wdCell.Range.Text = vaData(lnCountItems, i)` *after* formatting the value in the cell ?

Comment: You rewrite the cell content with the original value. May be you need `Else` statement and the assigning within the `If` statement.

Comment: Something like this `If whte = True Then wdCell.Range.Text = Format(Cell_Text, "0.00%") Else wdCell.Range.Text = vaData(lnCountItems, i) End If`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More like this maybe?

```vb
For Each wdCell In wdDoc.Tables(1).Columns(i).Cells
    If lnCountItems = rcount + 1 Then
        Exit For
    Else
        v = vaData(lnCountItems, i)                   'get value from array
        If IsNumeric(v) Then v = Format(v, "0.00%")   'format if numeric
        wdCell.Range.Text = v                         'put in cell
        lnCountItems = lnCountItems + 1
    End If
Next wdCell
```